# Torsion of a helix - where's my mistake?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

I'm calculating the torsion of a given helix three different ways, and getting two different answers.

The helix is given by parametric equations: $x(t)=\cos(2t)$, $y(t)=\frac{t}{2}$, $z(t)=\sin(2t)$, or more succinctly, $\mathbf{r}(t) = \left<\cos(2t),\frac{t}{2},\sin(2t)\right>$

The $2t$ is kind of annoying, but torsion is a purely geometric property, so a reparametrization shouldn't hurt. If $s=2t$, then our helix is $\left<\cos(s),\frac{s}{4},\sin(s)\right>$, and a well known formula for torsion, $\tau=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$ for the helix $\left<a\cos(t),a\sin(t),bt\right>$, gives us $\tau=\frac{-4}{17}$, taking it as negative because of reversed orientation. Great.

If I use the formula $\tau=\frac{|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}|\cdot\mathbf{a}'}{|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}|^2}$, I get the same answer. Even better.

Now, there's also the formula $\tau=-\mathbf{N}\cdot\mathbf{B}'$, where $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the unit normal and unit binormal vectors, respectively. This involves the most work, but it's the most illuminating as far as seeing information about the curve along the way. It's also leading me to the answer $\tau=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{17}}$.

I don't think this last formula is wrong, because I'm seeing it in multiple sources. The only thing I can think to do is to reproduce my work and try to figure out where I'm messing up:

$\mathbf{r}=\left<\cos(2t),\frac{t}{2},\sin(2t)\right>$

$\mathbf{v}=\left<-2\sin(2t),\frac{1}{2},2\cos(2t)\right>$

$|\mathbf{v}|=\sqrt{4+\frac14}=\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$

$\mathbf{T}=\frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\left<-4\sin(2t),1,4\cos(2t)\right>$

$\mathbf{T}'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\left<-8\cos(2t),0,-8\sin(2t)\right>$

$|\mathbf{T}'|=\frac{8}{\sqrt{17}}$

$\mathbf{N}=\frac{\mathbf{T}'}{|\mathbf{T}'|} = \left<-\cos(2t),0,-\sin(2t)\right>$

$\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{N} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\left<-\sin(2t),-4,\cos(2t)\right>$

$\mathbf{B}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\left<-2\cos(2t),0,-2\sin(2t)\right>$

$\tau=-\mathbf{N}\cdot\mathbf{B}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\left<\cos(2t),0,\sin(2t)\right>\cdot\left<-2\cos(2t),0,-2\sin(2t)\right>=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{17}}$

Why am I getting different answers? Please help!

---

Edit: Thanks to the initial comment below, I'm seeing my problem. I haven't been consistent about the meaning of the prime symbol. Every prime written here means $\frac{d}{dt}$, except for the one in the formula $\tau=-\mathbf{N}\cdot\mathbf{B}'$. That one is supposed to be a $\frac{d}{ds}$, and that was the source of my problem. When we don't have a nice formula for $s$, it's better to use the torsion formula $\tau=\frac{|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}|\cdot\mathbf{a}'}{|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}|^2}$. That one appears to work whether I've got an arc length parametrization or not.

Comment: You need an arclength parametrization to use the Frenet formulas. When you don't have an arclength parametrization, you need to use the chain rule to compute $d/ds$ in terms of $d/dt$. If your textbook doesn't show you examples, you might want to look at my differential geometry text — free .pdf you can find by clicking on a link in my profile.

Comment: I've read about the Frenet formulas now, and I'm still a little puzzled. It it specifically $\tau=-\mathbf{N}\cdot\mathbf{B}'$ that's the problem, or am I using any other formulas that depend on arc length parametrization? My textbook really doesn't make it clear which formulas depend on that and which ones don't.

Comment: They *all* do. For starters: If you don't move with constant speed, then your velocity and acceleration will *not* be orthogonal.

Comment: "All"? You're saying $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{r}'$ depends on arc length parametrization? That's not correct. What's more, no formula up there requires that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are orthogonal, at least not in a way I can see.

Comment: If they "all" depend on arc length parametrization, then what does one do it cases where it is prohibitively difficult to come up with an explicit one? In those cases, we can't calculate velocity, or acceleration, or a tangent vector, or a normal vector, or curvature, or torsion? Do you mean something different by "depends on" than I do?

Comment: In most cases one literally cannot reparametrize by arclength. Rather than give you an entire course, I'm again going to refer you to my text, which has plenty of explanations, derivations, examples, and exercises. It's all about the *chain rule*.

Comment: I'm pretty well aware of that. I'm also pretty well aware that the formula $\mathbf{v}(t)=\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}$ is true even when the curve isn't parametrized by arc length. Your initial comment was extremely helpful; thank you.